# SQL: Procedure not getting a date null

Tags: sql-server, date, stored-procedures, null

I’m executing a procedure like this:

```
EXEC myProcedure  @name = 'Smith',  @dateDeleted = NULL
```

I need all the Smith that don’t have a deleted date.

And this is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure]
  @name VARCHAR(8000) = NULL
 ,@dateDeleted VARCHAR(8000) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
    WITH t 
    (name
    ,dateDeleted
    )

AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    name,dateDeleted FROM mytable
     WHERE 
  (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
   AND (@dateDeleted IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, @dateDeleted, 102) = dateDeleted)

)
```

After the execution I have all the Smith but it does not pay any attention to the dateDeleted = NULL  .. I ge all the Smiths no matter if they have a deleted date

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: @name CHAR(1) = would only allow you to specify 'S' not 'Smith' .... VARCHAR(8000) for a date? Your data types look wrong.

Comment: You're not checking the table column:
 AND (@dateDeleted IS NULL...  should be
 AND (dateDeleted IS NULL...

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! So don't use `VARCHAR(8000)` for your `@dateDeleted` - use `DATE` or `DATETIME` (`DATETIME2` if you're on SQL Server 2008) !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your request if you pass NULL then a condition always true.Try this WHERE clause with [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) expression:

```
   WHERE (@name IS NULL OR @name = name)
   AND (COALESCE(@dateDeleted, dateDeleted) IS NULL 
     OR CONVERT(DATETIME, @dateDeleted, 102) = dateDeleted)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ansi nulls on

Execute:

```
set ansi_nulls on
```

And then execute the query.

Here is the explantion for this behaviour

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: sorry quite new to sql, where in my procedure should I do it?

Comment: @user712027 Set it before creating the procedure.